# Swift(xcode 9: code works in tutorial video):unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, fatal-error

I am learning the coding following the video on the website and the code works in the video but not works on my laptop. I checked several times I do the same coding as the man in the video, Could somebody help me check my code please, Thank you so much !! (Xcode 9)

```
import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var darkBlueBG: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var powerBtn: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var cloudHolder: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var rocket: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var hustleLbl: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var onLbl: UILabel!

var player: AVAudioPlayer!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "hustle-on", ofType: "wav")!
    let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
    do{
        player = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
        player.prepareToPlay()
    }catch let error as NSError {
        print(error.description)
    }

}


@IBAction func powerBtnPressed(_ sender: Any) {
    cloudHolder.isHidden = false
    darkBlueBG.isHidden = true
    powerBtn.isHidden = true
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2.3, animations: {
       self.rocket.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 100, width: 375, height: 435)
    }) { (finished) in
        self.hustleLbl.isHidden = false
        self.onLbl.isHidden = false
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Check that, Your `IBOutlet`s are connected or not

Comment: On which line app crashes ?

Comment: can you tell us which line in the code the force unwrap error is triggered? you could just use guard statements to prevent it.

Comment: try ? instead of ! with all variables  , it may look some one is nil and forcefully  unwrapping.

Comment: Another thing going wrong could be trying to force unwrap the path variable, Do you have the file hustle-on.wav in your project?

Comment: Hi  @JagdeepSingh , it's the line( let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "hustle-on", ofType: "wav")!)

Comment: @AdamFallon yes, the file is in the project, everything is right but just keep showing error

Comment: @Usss It means  "hustle-on.wav" file not exist in bundle of your project.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your IBOutlets are connected. You can do this by looking at the gutter next to them, and right clicking the circle that appears. If they are not connected, go to your storyboard and delete the half-connection, then re-add it.

Otherwise, use

```
guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "hustle-on", ofType: "wav")
else {
return
}
```

I assume that is where the error is occuring.

Comment: Hi, thank you so much for your help alec935. I checked all the IBOutlets and they are connected, and the "guard" code does not work .

Comment: No problem. after else { put in the code you want to run, should the guard fail. Guard is used to give an alternative to force unwrapping, should the unwrapped object be nil.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your comments, I just figured out that the audio is not selected as the membership of the project when I look up all the informations. It works now =)